Clarifying between sample date and input data
I'm reading section 2.6.3 from the book "The Elements of Statistical Learning" of "Trevor Hastie",
"Robert Tibshirani" and "Jerome Friedman" and I have a few question regarding the log-probability. As given in the book:
"Suppose we have a random sample $y_{i} (1),\ i=1,\ldots,N$ from a density
$\Pr_{\theta}(y)$ indexed by some parameters $\theta$. The log-probability of the observed
sample is
$$L(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\log\Pr_{\theta}(y_{i})$$
...
Least squares for the additive
error model $Y=f_{\theta}(X)+\varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$, is equivalent
to maximum likelihood using the conditional likelihood
$$\Pr(Y|X,\theta)=N(f_{\theta}(X),\sigma^{2}). \tag{2.34}$$
So although the additional assumption of normality seems more restrictive, the results are the
same. The log-likelihood of the data is
$$L(\theta)=-\frac{N}{2}\log(2\pi)-N\log\sigma-\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{
N}(y_{i}(2)-f_{\theta}(x_{i}))^{2}, \tag{2.35}$$"
At the beginning of section 2.6.3, it is assumed that the data is generated from a model $y_{i}(3)=f(x_{i})+\varepsilon_{i}$ and we are trying to approximate $f$ with some function $f_\theta$
To my understanding, $y_i$ (1) is generated from a function $f_\theta$, which is not similar to $y_i$ (3) in the original data, but in that case what is the meaning of using this methods and what is the (2) $y_i$
Is $y_i$ in (1), (2), and (3) similar to each others or there are any part of this book I'm misunderstanding? Any help and explanation is much appreciated.
